# Setting background color in print layout from Python console in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I would like to change the background color in my print layout from the Python console in QGIS. I can see some of the background color (currently white) near the corners of my layout and I would like to change this color.

---

I tried adding the suggested code to my for loop but was still getting the white background. Here is my code (see the `# Change background color` section at the end):

```
for i in range(1):# Testing
    
    # Load Raster File
    fn = "/".join([fldr, targ[i]])
    fi = QFileInfo(fn)
    fname = fi.baseName()
    rlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(fn, fname)
    
    renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rlayer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
    rlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
    
    # Create and Export Print Layout
    # Identify Layer for Map
    layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(fname)
    layer = layers[0]
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    manager = project.layoutManager()
    layoutName = " ".join(['Temp Pred Maps', str(i)])
    layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
    
    # Remove any duplicate layouts
    for i in layouts_list:
        if i.name() == layoutName:
            manager.removeLayout(i)
    
    # Add add layout to QGIS
    layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
    layout.initializeDefaults()
    layout.setName(layoutName)
    manager.addLayout(layout)
    
    # Change background color
    layout = manager.layouts()[0]
    items = layout.items()
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemMap):
            break
        
    mapItem = item
    mapItem.setBackgroundColor(QColor(60,255,240))
    layout.refresh()
```

[image]

Comment: how many layouts are in your manager? Could `layout = manager.layouts()[0]` be referencing the wrong one?

Comment: I have just seen that you can remove that line, as you reference your layout just a few lines before. And be sure to make the map item before you attempt to change the background colour. I don't see it being made in your code.

Comment: I tried removing `layout = manager.layouts()[0]` and substituting `[0]` for `[i]` to match my loop iteration but neither worked. I'm not getting any errors, the background is just not changing. Is `mapItem = item` not make the map item?

Comment: In short, no. That was just a general way of finding an *existing* map item. It was an abstract approach before I saw your code, which you added later. I have adjusted my answer to your specific case. In the code in your question, there is no map item being created, so the loop I initially wrote was just continuing through all the items, and ending up on your page item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
# these only need to be assigned once, so I moved them out of the loop
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()

# get current extent of map canvas (you may want to use a different extent, this was just for the example)
ext = iface.mapCanvas().extent()

for i in range(1):# Testing

    # Load Raster File
    fn = "/".join([fldr, targ[i]])
    fi = QFileInfo(fn)
    fname = fi.baseName()
    rlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(fn, fname)
    
    renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rlayer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
    rlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
    
    # Create and Export Print Layout
    layoutName = " ".join(['Temp Pred Maps', str(i)])
    layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
    
    # Remove any duplicate layouts
    for j in layouts_list:           # changed i for j to prevent confusion with the i in outer loop
        if j.name() == layoutName:
            manager.removeLayout(j)
    
    # Add add layout to QGIS
    layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
    layout.initializeDefaults()
    layout.setName(layoutName)
    manager.addLayout(layout)
    
    # create map item
    mymap = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
    mymap.setRect(20, 20, 20, 20)
    mymap.setCrs(rlayer.crs())
    
    # add layers to map
    ms = QgsMapSettings()
    ms.setLayers([rlayer]) # set layers to be mapped 

    # set the map extent from the map canvas (line 6)
    mymap.setExtent(ext)
    
    # arbitrary map scale, will need adjusting
    mymap.setScale(250000) 
    
    # change background colour (RGBAlpha)
    mymap.setBackgroundColor(QColor(60,255,240,255))
    
    # add map to layout
    layout.addLayoutItem(mymap)

    # adjust the size of map
    mymap.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(200, 200, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
    
    # refresh the layout
    layout.refresh()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble integrating this into my for loop. I'll add my code above.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have the same map background color as the page, you can disable background color for the map item.

```
mapItem.setBackgroundEnabled(False)
```

[image]